# Exporting swf file Flash CS6

Tags: flash-cs6

I need to export classes that do not have connection with Symbols, sprites and images in the library (only action script codes). But every time I export the SWF, it exports only ActionScripts that have a connection to the library.

In Publish Settings my source path is linked with all ActionScripts

Comment: Create a dummy class linked to the Library and **import** there all the classes you want to be compiled.

Comment: As I understand it, I have to create a class and within the code of this class put the code import *? If so, how will I import more than 1000 files

Comment: Import them by package import, I guess? Like > import flash.events.*

Comment: There's another way. You can create an SWC library out of these extra classes and include this file in Publish Settings > AS3 Settings > Library path. You will need **mxmlc** command line tool from AIR SDK or Flex SDK and have quite a read about all the options, but in the ultimate end that will pay off because Flash IDE won't have to compile all 1000 classes each time you publish your application.

Comment: I tried the same SWC as you said but when I exported nothing has changed. The mxmlc in Flash Builder 4.7 I can do the file

Comment: I am trying the following command: mxmlc "pathtoas\1.as" -compiler.include-libraries "pathtooneSWC" "pathtosecondSWC" . 
Everything happens fine however the file is 864KB and does not have some images. If I compile only one or the other (besides the two) compiles right. A SWC has only images and classes of it. The other contains only codes. 
The correct size would be between 8MB ~ 9MB